# How to make mysql semi-repl not timeout?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog

Since MySQL 5.5, we have [semisync](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html), but semisync will switch off when receive semi sync [ACK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/semi-sync-ack-packet.html) timeout.So, is there any way to not timeout ?

I find a variable for mariadb [rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/semisynchronous-replication/).Also in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout)

```
Range: 0 to 1844674407370955161
```

So, I can make the semi sync not timeout if I set this to 1844674407370955161.

Comment: (A) what happened when you tried it? (B) are you sure you really want to do this?

Comment: I try to implement a binlog proxy level, I want the mysql wait my ACK.Something like a sync-repl, just trying.